# Rails and Python hosting

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, apache

I am trying to host some files/rails app in the port `8080` for external access. For Python I am using the `SimpleHTTPServer` module, and for Rails, webrick.

However, both of them does not work very well. I don't get the response back, and, sometimes, if I get it, it's VERY slow. Nevertheless, apache works very well on the port `8080` (I am not running them at the same time).

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Python, but Webrick is not meant to be used for an in-production application—you didn't mention if this application was in production, though you did say 'external access'.

For Rails, have a look at [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/).

Comment: I just want to show to my friends my site while i'm developing on windows. I can't do that on webrick?

Comment: Sure, but it's going to be slow as hell. If you don't want Passenger, another option is to have a look at Mongrel (though I'm not sure what support for it on Windows is like) http://github.com/fauna/mongrel.